# neo4j cypher WITH - return data from first query if no match in second query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a cypher query that looks like the following:

```
MATCH (a)-[]->(b)
WHERE (condition #1)
WITH a, b
MATCH (a)-[]->(c)
WHERE (condition #2)
RETURN a, b, c
```

My data is such that the first part of the query will return "a" and "b" by itself. However, the query returns no data if the second WHERE condition fails. I expected data for "a" and "b" with NULL  for "c" How would I be able to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: but make sure to use indexes, labels and property filtering, you might also want to use `WITH distinct a,b` or `WITH a, collect(b) as coll_b` to get cardinalities down.

Comment: Thanks Michael. The actually query does have node labels.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding [`OPTIONAL`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-optional-match.html) before the second match should solve the problem.

```
MATCH (a)-[]->(b)
WHERE (condition #1)
WITH a, b
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[]->(c)
WHERE (condition #2)
RETURN a, b, c
```